# Python library seaborn doesn't work properly in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib, seaborn

I tried to run a Python script in Visual Studio that includes the Python libraries matplotlib and seaborn. A script that includes matplotlib only runs correctly and displays the plot however, a script that includes seaborn doesn't do anything (no errors). I installed the libraries by installing Anaconda.

The code that works properly is an example from the website of matplotlib :

```
"""
========
Barchart
========

A bar plot with errorbars and height labels on individual bars
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
men_means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
men_std = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, men_means, width, color='r', yerr=men_std)

women_means = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
women_std = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, women_means, width, color='y', yerr=women_std)

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))


def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

If I run the code :

```
# First, we'll import pandas, a data processing and CSV file I/O library
import pandas as pd

# We'll also import seaborn, a Python graphing library
import warnings # current version of seaborn generates a bunch of warnings that we'll ignore
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="dark", color_codes=True)

# Next, we'll load the Iris flower dataset, which is in the "../input/" directory
iris = pd.read_csv("Iris.csv") # the iris dataset is now a Pandas DataFrame

# Let's see what's in the iris data - Jupyter notebooks print the result of the last thing you do
iris.head(1000)

# Press shift+enter to execute this cell
```

nothing happens in Visual Studio but running the code on

https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/python-data-visualizations

gives a correct output.

The dataset that I used can be found at :

https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/python-data-visualizations/data

How can I get seaborn working in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing two entirely different codes here. The first code produces a plot in a new window. The second code does not have any output. As the comment inside the code states, "Jupyter notebooks print the result of the last thing you do".

Visual Studio does not do this; or more generally, python does not do this. If you want to print something in python, you need the `print` statement or function.

In python 2, do

```
print iris.head(1000)
```

In python 3, do

```
print (iris.head(1000))
```

All of this has nothing to do with seaborn.